# SoftLayer Vulnerability Scan - Strange Exception

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to use SoftLayer's API to execute vulnerability scans on multiple hosts from Python. To be more precise, I'm trying to scan around 200 hosts. I have noticed the presence of request throttling so I'm starting the scans 1 host per minute.
Everything works perfectly fine up to around 63-64 hosts. I can see the scans running. But, after that if I try to start a new scan I receive the following exception.

```
Unable to create a new object of type SoftLayer_Network_Security_Scanner_Request_Nessus. Make sure the authentication method is correct.
```

Could someone please help me to figure out what could be the issue as the root cause of the exception is definitely not incorrect authentication method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know issue, you need to provide the accountId, ipAddress, guestId or hardwareId.

It was answered before here [SoftLayer Vulnerability Scan Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143386/softlayer-vulnerability-scan-python)

Also you can review https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/jmarhee/nessus-security-scans-using-softlayer-api

Regards,

Comment: Sorry, but my issue is not about that. I'm sending all the required details with the requests. As you can see I have mentioned that scans are running perfectly fine until I attempt to execute the 64th scan as that and any future requests will result in the exception I have mentioned.

Comment: I'm unable to get that error, could you post the code you are using to scan all those 200 hosts?.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, in my case the error was raised when was set **hostId** instead of **hardwareId**. Please verify if it is the same case. The correct configuration is **hardwareId for bare metal servers** and **guestId for Virtual Guests**

Comment: The issue was exactly what you have just mentioned. I was not using the hardwareId. I have fixed, tested and now works perfectly fine. Thank you very much.